# How to write excel formula to return column header name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am looking to allow users to select the modules. Diving deeper, the users can select base on syllabus. Thereafter, it will tell them which courses (aka the column header), which matches the condition base on the rows with "Y".

> > ```
> > Example  If the following is selected:
> > - Data Governance (Policy and Process)
> > - Data Analytics Project (Problem Statement Formulation)
> > - Data Exploration (Exploratory Analysis)
> > - Data Exploration (Machine Learning) 
> >  It will all return both CourseID1 & CourseID2,  If Data Analytics Project (Data Handling & Ethics) selected it will not return CourseID1. Only CourseID2 will be returned
> > ```

I have attached a screen shot of the Excel Table. The flow is as follows:
step 1: user selects module
step 2: user select the syllabus that's tied to the module (a dependent selection from step 1)
step3: Output for the suitable courses is shown!

[image]

How to write such formula?

The formula I used was wrong

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$E$72="Y")*($B$2:$B$72=B2)*(COLUMN($A$2:$E$72))))-COLUMN($A$1)+1)
```

It does not return both CourseID1 and CourseID2 when the right criteria is being selected.

Comment: Why not ID1 for policy&process since your table shows "y"…

Comment: @SolarMike I have rephrased it, All should return ID1 and ID2. If Data Analytics Project (Data Handling & Ethics) selected it will not return CourseID1. Only CourseID2 will be returned

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya My excel Version 16.0.15028.20160. The expected output is to return courseID that suits the requirement

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya  I tried this formula "=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$E$72="Y")*($B$2:$B$72=Sheet2!B2)*(COLUMN($A$2:$E$72))))-COLUMN($A$1)+1)"

Comment: That seems a working a formula, what happened then?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya It does not return both CourseID1 and CourseID2 when the right criteria is being selected

Comment: Yes i see now. its not working

Comment: @Lawrence I am not in front of the computer this is untested could you try this once and let me know, `=INDEX($D$1:$E$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($B$2:$E$9)-COLUMN($B$2)+1)/(($A13=$B$2:$B$9)*($B13=$C$2:$C$9)*(D$2:D$9="Y")),COLUMN(A1)))` and do you want to return both in a single cell ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya it gives me "#num" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what I have ***tried***, assuming you are using **O365**

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `A17` using `FILTERXML()`, `XLOOKUP()` , `TEXTJOIN()` , `INDEX()` , `SUBSTITUTE()` & `COLUMN()` functions.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX($A$1:$E$1,,INDEX(--(XLOOKUP(
FILTERXML("<p><w>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A12,"&",""),", ","</w><w>")&"</w></p>","//w")&
FILTERXML("<p><w>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A15,"&",""),", ","</w><w>")&"</w></p>","//w"),
SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$9,"&","")&SUBSTITUTE($C$2:$C$9,"&",""),$D$2:$E$9)="Y")*(COLUMN($D$1:$E$1)),1)))
```

---

**Or**, If you are using **O365** and presently in **Office Insiders Beta Channel Version** then using `TEXTSPLIT()` instead of `FILTERXML()`

• Formula used in cell `A18`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX($A$1:$E$1,,(TRANSPOSE(XLOOKUP(
TEXTSPLIT(A12,,", ")&TEXTSPLIT(A15,,", "),$B$2:$B$9&$C$2:$C$9,
$D$2:$E$9))="Y")*COLUMN($D$1:$E$1)))
```

---